# Combine multiple rows into one row and into table MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am sorry for my english) I having 3 tables. Next type:

Table 1 - users

```
--------------------------------
| id     | email    | password |
--------------------------------
| 1      | 1        | 3        |
| 2      | 1        | 4        |
| 3      | 1        | 3        |
| 4      | 1        | 4        |
| 5      | 2        | 3        |
| 6      | 2        | 4        |
| 7      | 2        | 3        |
| 8      | 2        | 4        |
--------------------------------
```

table2: scores

```
---------------------------
 id     | idUser    | nameScore|
--------------------------------
| 1      | 1        | df       |
| 2      | 1        | sa       |
| 3      | 1        | as       |
| 4      | 1        | 4        |
| 5      | 2        | 3        |
| 6      | 2        | 4        |
| 7      | 2        | 3        |
| 8      | 2        | 4        |
-------------------------------|
```

table3: payment

```
--------------------------------------------------
| id     | idScorePayer   |idScorePayee|  money
--------------------------------------------------
| 1      | 1              |    2       |   1000
| 2      | 2              |    4       |   700
| 3      | 3              |    1       |   1500
| 4      | 4              |    3       |   9000
---------------------------------------------------
```

What Im trying to output:

```
-----------------------------------------------
| id     | emailPayer   | emailPayee      | money
-----------------------------------------------
| 1      | yellow@      | cookies@        |
| 2      | yellow@      | milk@           |
| 3      | yellow@      | cookies@        |
| 4      | yellow@      | milk@           |
| 5      | blue@        | cookies@        |
| 6      | blue@        | milk@           |
| 7      | blue@        | cookies@        |
| 8      | blue@        | milk@           |
-----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: can you structure your tables a bit better? as well as explain the values a bit more?

Comment: Your question isnt clear, where you get yellow, blue, cookies, milk??  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: the email table is not shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below query should work:

```
select u1.email as emailPayer, u2.email as emailPayee, amount
from users u1 join scores s1 on u1.id = s1.idUser
join payment on s1.id = payment.idScorePayer
join scores s2 on payment.idScorePayee = s2.idUser
join users u2 on u2.id = s2.idUser
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a MySQL instance to test against, and I'm guess on the email table, but I think it'd be something like this:

```
SELECT
   users.id,
   email1.email_name "emailPayer",
   email2.email_addr "emailPayee",
   payment.money
FROM
   users
     JOIN scores ON (users.id = scores.idUser)
     JOIN payment ON (scores.id = payment.idScorePayer)
     JOIN email email1 ON (scores.idScorePayer = email.id)
     JOIN email email2 ON (scores.idSCorePayee = email.id)
```